# deal with NA's when using tapply

Tags: r, tapply

Consider the following example:

```
Factor <- c(rep('Male', 10),rep('Female', 10))
Age <- sample(30:80,20)

df1 <- data.frame(Factor, Age)

with(df1, tapply(Age, Factor, mean))
```

The final command gives us the average age for both sexes. Now let say one inout is marked with a NA. How can we overcome this issue?

```
df1$Age[15] <- NA
with(df1, tapply(Age, Factor, mean))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arguments of the function being used in `tapply`, in this case `mean`.

If you take a look at `?mean`, you'll see that the default for `mean` is `na.rm = False`. Just change it:

```
tapply(df1$Age, df1$Factor, mean, na.rm = T)
```

Alternatively, using `with`:

```
with(df1, tapply(Age, Factor, mean, na.rm = T))
```